# I was able to push logs from local machine to AI in azure using telemetry service. How do I push the same from AI to OMS in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-oms

I want to visualize logs in OMS(Log analytics workspace). I was able to push logs from local machine to AI in azure using the telemetry configuration. Ho do I push the same from AI to OMS(Log analytics workspace) in azure. (AI - azure application insights)

Comment: Isn't OMS [depricated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/oms-portal-transition)? What is it you want to really do?

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/oms-portal-transition#application-insights-connector-and-solution

Comment: By OMS I meant Log Analytics workspace.

Comment: If any of the answers below give you an adequate answer please [upvote and/or accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you meant OMS as Log Analytics workspace then [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource) might help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to push it to Log Analytics, you can query directly, and use the result for visualization using the [app expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query#identifying-an-application):

```
app("name-of-your-ai-resource").requests
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, url, resultCode
```

Or you convert your Application Insights to use a Log Analytics Workspace for storage directly as KrishnaG-MSFT suggests. There is a conversion guide for that, found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource).

Be aware though:

> Choosing to migrate will instead change the location where new data is written to a Log Analytics workspace while preserving access to your classic resource data.

And do mind, you can create rich, interactive visualizations in App Insigths directly using [workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-overview).